# Plotting a y=mx+c graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I currently have an equation **Tn/v=P*Rn**, but for ease's sake lets say it's y=mx.

How would I go about plotting this using python if I wanted to calculate 'm' as a gradient.
I already know the y value and the x value, how could I get this plotted and then find the gradient?

I am currently using 'matplotlib' as the external library.

Comment: Are you wanting to compute `m` from `Tn/v=P*Rn`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of x and y data points, you can find the gradient by applying the definition of a gradient of a straight line.

$$m = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$$

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
dx = x[-1] - x[0]
dy = y[-1] - y[0]
m = dy/dx
```

this indexes the first and last element of each list, finds the difference between the elements, and divides the two. This is your gradient.

Edit - You can then use matplotlib to plot a straight line to your graph, using your calculated m value.

Answer (score 0):

You can regress a line through those points using:

```
fit = np.polyfit(x,y,deg=1)
```

and plot the line using:

```
ax.plot(x, fit[0] * x + fit[1])
```